# Why are R scripts inside of Databricks notebooks creating writeLines errors?

Tags: r, databricks

I'm using R in Databricks.  R Studio runs fine and executes from the Databricks cluster.  I would like to transition from R Studio to notebooks.  However, I am repeatedly getting this error when running the simplest R scripts (one-liner assignments) inside notebooks:

```
Error in writeLines(DB_STREAM_BEACON_STRING_START__, DATABRICKS_STDERRCONNSTREAM__) : 
  invalid connection
Some(<code style = 'font-size:10p'>  </code>)
```

Comment: Please at least provide the code you ran.

Comment: Invalid connection indicates that a connection to which you're trying to write is either incorrectly specified, or has closed. It's difficult to say more than that as we are not working in your databricks environment.

Comment: x <- 1 creates the error.  The simplest script will return this error.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out after several hours of research and troubleshooting.  This problem arises from Rmarkdown failing to write various types of common Rmarkdown output (most likely viewer output) to stdout.  Rather than directly running `rmarkdown::render()` from the notebook, run `R -e 'rmarkdown::render() > out.txt` as a shell script in the notebook, redirecting output to a text file.